# mySQL JOIN of several tables

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, group-concat

I do have the following three tables in a MySQL-DB (InnoDB)

```
UserTab
ID | Name  | ---
------------------
 1 | Tom   |
 2 | Dick  |
 3 | Harry |

EventTab
ID | Name      | ---
------------------
 1 | Easter    |
 2 | Holidays  |
 3 | ThxGiving |
 4 | Christmas |

ParticipationTab
ID | UserID | EventID
---------------------
 1 | 1      | 1
 2 | 1      | 2
 3 | 1      | 3
 4 | 2      | 1
 5 | 2      | 4
 6 | 3      | 3
```

And I want to achieve the follwing result with my query:

```
QueryResultTab
UserTab.Name | EventTab.Name | NoPart | Names
-----------------------------------------------
 Tom         | Easter        | 2      | Tom, Dick
 Tom         | Holidays      | 1      | Tom
 Tom         | ThxGiving     | 2      | Tom, Harry
 Dick        | Easter        | 2      | Tom, Dick 
 Dick        | Christmas     | 1      | Dick
 Harry       | ThxGiving     | 2      | Tom, Harry
```

I do know about Count() combined with GROUP to get the number of participants
I know about group-concat to get the "Names".

```
SELECT Event, GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY Name ASC SEPARATOR ', ') as Names  
FROM  
(SELECT ID as UserID, Name FROM X_Users WHERE ConditionA) AS UserTab  
INNER JOIN  
(SELECT EventID, UserID FROM X_Participation WHERE ConditionB) AS ParticipationTab  
ON UserTab.UserID = ParticipationTab.UserID  
INNER JOIN  
(SELECT ID as EventID, Event FROM X_Events WHERE ConditionC) AS EventTab  
ON ParticipationTab.EventID = EventTab.EventID  
GROUP BY EventTab.EventID
```

This gives me:

```
ConcatTab
EventTab.Name | Names  
---------------------------  
Easter        | Tom, Dick  
Holidays      | Tom  
ThxGiving     | Tom, Harry  
Easter        | Tom, Dick  
Christmas     | Dick  
ThxGiving     | Tom, Harry
```

I know about JOINs as you can see. Probably I could use LEFT or RIGHT JOINs as well for this.

For the other parts I use this query:

```
SELECT Name, Event, NoPart   
FROM (SELECT ID as UserID, Name FROM X_Users WHERE ConditionA) AS UserTab    
INNER JOIN (SELECT EventID, UserID FROM X_Participation WHERE ConditionB) AS PartTab   
ON UserTab.UserID = PartTab.UserID  
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID as EventID, Event FROM X_Events WHERE ConditionC) AS EvTab  
ON PartTab.EventID = EvTab.EventID  
INNER JOIN (SELECT EventID as CntID, COUNT(*) AS NoPart FROM X_Participation WHERE ConditionB) AS CntTab    
ON EvTab.EventID = CntTab.CntID  
ORDER BY UserTab.UserID
```

This gives me:

```
CountTab
UserTab.Name | EventTab.Name | NoPart 
--------------------------------------
 Tom         | Easter        | 2      
 Tom         | Holidays      | 1      
 Tom         | ThxGiving     | 2      
 Dick        | Easter        | 2      
 Dick        | Christmas     | 1      
 Harry       | ThxGiving     | 2
```

But how to combine/merge ConcatTab and CountTab into QueryResultTab?  I want to retrieve the result table in PHP row by row with mysql_fetch_assco().
  Please don't tell me about PDO, etc. I know about it.

The other option - what I try to avoid - is do it within a PHP-loop and use numerous tiny SQL-queries to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, you want all the rows in the participation table, with information from the dimensions.  Then you want a summary of that table.

Here is an approach that uses a subquery in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT u.name, e.name, p2.numPart, p2.Names
FROM X_Participation p INNER JOIN  
     X_Users u 
     ON u.UserID = p.UserID INNER JOIN  
     X_Events e
     ON p.EventID = e.EventID INNER JOIN
     (SELECT p2.EventId, COUNT(*) as numPart,
             GROUP_CONCAT(u2.name SEPARATOR ', ') as names
      FROM X_Participation p2 INNER JOIN  
           X_Users u2 
           ON u2.UserID = p2.UserID
      GROUP BY p2.EventId
     ) p2
     ON p2.EventId = p.EventId;
```

Notes:

- If you are going to use table aliases (which you should), make them shorter, not longer than the table names.
- Don't use subqueries unnecessarily.  This is especially true in MySQL which materializes subqueries.
- You can put additional conditions in a `WHERE` clause of the outer query.

Comment: Side question: Would it improve performance to create a temporary table to replace the subquery prior to running this query, or does MySQL handle this automatically?

Comment: @Pharaoh . . . If performance is an issue, there might be other ways to make it work.  Creating a temporary table -- particularly with the right index -- might be a little faster.  I don't think it is worth the extra effort.

Comment: @Gordon, thanks for the quick & working answer. The long aliases were just for demonstration.

Comment: @togath please accept the answer if it has helped you solve the problem.